# Chat with an Expert?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I'm getting a "chat with an expert" popup.  What is this?  Clicking it "connects me with an expert", but I'm not sure who.  Is this an SE add-on, or some weird ad-ware that's popping through?

---

Here's a screen clip of the popup that I got right here!  I wonder if it has to do with the "how do you recognize an expert" post on the main site.

[image]

Comment: What website is it taking you to connect you with an expert?

Comment: Unknown.  It brings up a window as a popup. As a matter of fact, just got a popup on the meta site that I captured as a screen snip.  I'll post it in an answer, as I can't do it in a comment

Comment: Consider yourself lucky!  Try to learn whatever pearls of wisdom you can from the expert.  Just don't ask them what day it is.

Comment: Seems to be going around.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert  -- Appears to be an AI April Fools-bot

Comment: Forgot it was 2013/4/1. My mistake.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out if it has an (hidden) Easter egg, but no luck so far.

Comment: Nah, @jippie, that was Sunday ;)

Comment: @ScottSeidman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Monday

Comment: @jippie Easter Monday is a Sunday, according to the Catholic Church :)

Comment: @CamilStaps not according to my calendar/computer/telephone/tablet/...

Answer (score 6):

It's a beta of a new SE interface.  They are trying to see whether they can get rid of the troublesome users and replace them with a universal AI answer bot.  People make mistakes, don't write clearly, slip decimal points, etc.  We'll all be unnecessary soon, but for now they still have a few details to work out.  The response to one of life's great questions wasn't quite ready for prime time yet:

[image]

### Added:

The bot isn't really all that sophisticated.  I remember a program from the late 1970s called Eliza that wasn't much worse than this.  This is a long way from passing the Touring Test.

I did another one to see what it can do.  I noticed the dialog box had a link at the top to the [transcript of the session](http://adviza.stackexchange.com/transcript/PseVq3F9vECm).  I wonder if it's possible to see other transcripts.  Deleting the leaf name from that link doesn't get you to a page with a bunch of transcripts.  There are probably some good ones in there.

Comment: SE is probably wanting their programmers to spend more time on monetizing the site than improving an Eliza program (I think "Eliza" is a name of the class now). Besides if it passed the Touring test it would be less fun as a 4/1 program.

Comment: Olin, I remember using emacs to pass Zippy the Pinhead quotes to Eliza.  You'd have pages and pages of wonderful dialog before you could even stop the script.  Found it!! http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/lol/pinhead.html

Comment: Drat-- had to install emacs and run it.  Eliza is good old Eliza, but all Zippy wants to say is "Legally-imposed CULTURE-reduction is CABBAGE-BRAINED!"

Comment: Touring test? Where's it touring?

Comment: if you just said, "ni" it had some funny responses.

Answer (score 5):

It's a new functionality of EE.stackexchange, instead of asking questions to the community, it'll answer whatever problem you have instantly!

Answer (score 1):

Heh.  Any entity who intentionally answers questions or guides an online conversation *in order to perpetuate the conversation*  ...is defined as an "internet troll."    If Eliza can't detect the natural end of a thread, and then cease replying, then Eliza is revealed to not be human (as we occasionally discover our online opponents to be trolls rather than humans!)